# ReactJS - fetch function: ¿Por qué tengo el error "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, reactjs

Estoy usando reactjs , mysql y php y no puedo conectarme a la base de datos, me sale el sgte error

> App.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at App.js:17

```
import '../App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Tabela from './Tabela';

class App extends Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state=({
            db: []
        });
        this.exibirCarros();
    }

    exibirCarros(){
        fetch("http://localhost/Api/classConexion.php")
        .then((response)=>response.json())
        .then((responseJson)=>
        {
            this.setState({
                db: responseJson
            });
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
          <div>
              <Tabela arrayCarros={this.state.db } />

          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

---

alguien podria ayudarme, no que se pueda hacer, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Debieras primero ver si tu api en PHP puede retornar los datos de conección como un JSON para que sea mas facil trabajar con eso y evitar errores. Luego puedes validar la respuesta para evitar errores. Ejemplo:

```js
var processStatus = function (response) {
    if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 304) {
        return Promise.resolve(response)
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText))
    }
};

fetch("http://localhost/Api/classConexion.php")
   .then(processStatus).
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(res => {
        this.setState({
                db: res.db
        });                
   });
```

En tu API de PHP para la respuesta puedes usar esto:

```php
$jsonData['db'] = 'nombreDB';
echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error está aquí:

```
.then((response)=>response.json())
```

Ocurre porque la repuesta del fetch no puede ser trasformada a JSON de manera correcta, ya sea porque no retorna nada o la respuesta no tiene formato json.

Intenta hacer esto y ve que en la consola del navegador que te responde el servidor, para verificar que te retorna lo correcto:

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state= {
        db: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch("http://localhost/Api/classConexion.php")
    .then( response => response.text())
    .then( text => console.log(text));
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
          <Tabela arrayCarros={this.state.db } />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Y te recomiendo que no ejecutes métodos o sentencias que hagan cambios de estado en el constructor**